# Is it posible to make sql execute one request at a time from different users?

Tags: php, sql

I am building a subscription system which, for each category, has a limit of subscribers. The language that I am using is PHP, and the database is MySQL.

The idea is that, in the landing page, the users select a category to subscribe. In there, there is an input with the available categories (the ones which do no pass the limit of subscribers yet).

The code that I wrote for subscribing a user is the following:

```php
$array_m = "SELECT * FROM talleres WHERE taller = '$tallerM'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $array_m);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if($row['user_email'] === '') {
      $row['user_email'] = json_encode(array());
    }

    $arrayDecoded = json_decode($row['user_email']);
    $session_email = $_SESSION['u_email'];
    // $usersYoga = array();
    array_push($arrayDecoded, $session_email);

    $arrayEncoded = json_encode($arrayDecoded);

    $sql_t = "UPDATE talleres SET user_email='$arrayEncoded' WHERE taller='$tallerM'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql_t);
```

And the code that I wrote for showing which are the available subscriptions is:

```php
$tallerCheck = "SELECT user_email FROM talleres WHERE taller='$value'";
          $result = mysqli_query($conn, $tallerCheck);
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
          $rowDecoded = json_decode($row['user_email']);
          if(count($rowDecoded) >= $num) {
            // Code for showing only the available options in the front-end
            echo "<script>blockTaller('".$value."')</script>";
          }
```

I am expecting that when users subscribe, the number of subscribers increases, and when the limit is reached, that the category is not shown (or it becomes blocked).
When one user at a time subscribes there is no problem. However, when many users subscribe at the same time, they are all subscribed, without the limit being checked for each user (for instance, lets say that for category A the limit is 15, and the number of subscribers is 14; when two users subscribe to A at the same time, they are both subscribed, surpassing the limit, and that is wrong).

Do you have any idea of what could be done? Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Corrected!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot avoid two people both being offered the chance to subscribe even when only one place is available.

However you can ensure that only one of them succeeds if both attempt to subscribe at the same time.

It can be as simple as repeating the test for the length to protect the update in your first code block:

```
$sql_t = "UPDATE talleres SET user_email='$arrayEncoded' WHERE taller='$tallerM'";
if (count($arrayDecoded)<$num){
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql_t);
}
```

This solution may result in user A getting the last subscription then user B replacing user A as the last subscriber. If it's important, you can avoid that situation by using transactions.

BTW:
It is not a good idea to store the subscribers as a json encoded list. You should use a two column subscription table instead. You have a many-to-many relationship between the entities **taller** and **user**

Comment: @TomasMudano . . . Don't munger query strings!  Learn to use parameters.  It is sad that an accepted answer does not use parameters.

Comment: The OP is storing JSON encoded arrays in a database table - he's some way from using RDBS well. I'm framing my answer based on where he is rather than where he should be.